# Adding a condition to the findOneOptions query in the WHERE block, but the result only matches the first one

Tags: node.js

I want to add a condition to the findOneOptions query in the WHERE block, but the result only matches the first one.

```
async getListOfCustomer(customerId: string) {
    return await this.historyCallRepository.find({
      where: {
        customerId,
        callFrom: CALL_FROM.CB || CALL_FROM.KH,
      },
      order: {
        createdAt: 'DESC',
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is this typeORM? If so, please edit your question and update taglist

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you intended to use the `$or` operator:

```
return await this.historyCallRepository.find({
    where: {
        $or: [{ customerId }, { callFrom: CALL_FROM.CB || CALL_FROM.KH }],
    },
})
```